# Laravel db:select on controller

Tags: laravel-5.7

How can I select a column from a db and store it in a variable in the controller to operate with it?
I’m starting on php/laravel
I tried this

```
 $nametable = DB::table('nametable')->get();
 $variable =  $nametable->nameofcolumn;
```

And i tried this too:

```
$variable = DB::table('nametable')->select('nameofcolumn')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB` facade, in your second case, will return an object. You can then access the name of the column using the `->` operator.

For example:

```
$result = DB::table('table')
    ->select('column')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->first();
```

To access the `column`, you would then do

```
$result->column;
```

The following can also be a decent alternative:

```
$variable = DB::table('table')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->value('column'); // The value is returned directly.
```

Now, in your first case:

```
$results = DB::table('nametable')
    ->get();
```

This, would return an instance of [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections). You would then need to loop over the collection to access individual *rows*

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result->column; // for example
}
```

You could also play around with this [example.](https://implode.io/5mfrj1)